# Forcing an application to use an unsecured network not my internal network on a Windows XP desktop

Tags: networking

I have a Windows xp desktop with two network cards. One connected to a public unsecure network and the other connected to a secure LAN. I want to force an application to run on the unsecure network while leaving the secure LAN connection enabled. Is this possible and if so how secure is it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a virtual PC should work for this.

One virtual PC software which might work: [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org).
In [Chapter 6](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) of its [user manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/) it discusses networking. The Bridged Networking option would probably be the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if a virtual machine is the way to go. I have two separate ethernet connections coming into two different cards simultaneously so they are already connected to both networks I just want to force Skype to go out over the unsecure connection and not the LAN connection. Plus I want this to be as seamless as possible for the user. Instead of using a VM I would just teach them how to disable the LAN connection which I don't really want to do either. If anyone has any other ideas I would really appreciate the help.